# list comphrension on nested distionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dict like so:

```
tt={'plot1':[
      {'var': 'ok__you', 'uuid': '98782098109'},
      {'var': 'hdg__akj', 'uuid': '712837901'}
      ], 
    'plot2': [
      {'var': 'ok__you2', 'uuid': '987820981092'},
      {'var': 'hdg__akj2', 'uuid': '7128379012'}
    ]}
```

I am trying to get all the `uuids` into one single list, so, I do:

```
lst=[v_i['uuid'] for v_i in value for key,value in tt.items()]
```

and I get thrown:

```
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

I have no clue why this is - I have specified the `value` in the `tt.items()` iteration - not sure why this error is being thrown?

Would apreciate any tips!

Comment: `lst = [k['uuid'] for k in tt for k in tt[k]]`

Answer (score 2):

You swapped the order of the two for loops

```
lst=[v_i['uuid'] for key,value in tt.items() for v_i in value]
```

The output will then be

```
['98782098109', '712837901', '987820981092', '7128379012']
```

Also since you are not using the key, you could just iterate on the values of the dictionaries

```
lst=[v_i['uuid'] for value in tt.values() for v_i in value]
```

Comment: Thanks Davesh - probably because I am working a bit late today :)

Comment: No worries @JohnJ :) It happens to the best of us, if the answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted :)